# Heroku push without bundle install (windows)

Tags: git, heroku

I just wonder why when I push some changes to heroku that are **not in gemfile** it always runs bundle install, fetches and installs all the gems. Is it possible not to do that?

Answer (score 1):

On windows bundle creates gemfile.lock that contains two strings:

PLATFORMS
 x86-mingw32

I've written a script that cleans these strings from file before adding, committing to git to push to heroku - that works.

Comment: This sounds dodgy uh? I reckon the bundler guys left it there for some reason, wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure include both the GemFile and the Gemfile.lock to the repository!!! Then it should work fine. Dont igonre both these files in the .gitignore file and also install a bundler version >= 1.0.0 on your local machine to generate the Gemfile.lock.

Update your Gemfile.lock by using the command bundle update

Remove the Gemfile.lock from your .gitignore file

Comment: While push Heroku says: Windows Gemfile.lock detected, ignoring it.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR : Remove the Gemfile.lock from your .gitignore file

Comment: I have not gemfile.lock in the gitignore file.